# Large texture2d in XNA

Tags: xna, texture2d

I am trying to store and display a map for an RTS game as a texture2d, but the map is too big, and I get the error "XNA Framework HiDef profile supports a maximum Texture2D size of 4096". The reason I wanted the entire map in one texture was so I could take advantage of the source/destination rectnagle draw method that spriteBatch has for use in the games camera. If this isn't obviously a bad idea, how can I store and display large images?

Comment: You could probably load your image into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and make a method that will retrieve the required rectangle from it.

Comment: I already have the data drawn to a render target, but I guess it simply isn't possible to re-draw it all with one texture? I could write a method to divide up the texture into smaller textures, but that kind of defeats the purpose of trying to avoid looping through all the map tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get around the texture size limit in XNA. It's quite reasonable to use multiple textures and draw them in different places. It is only a small amount of extra logic to handle the borders.

Don't forget that a 4096 by 4096 texture is already a whopping 64MB of texture memory, uncompressed (and at least 10MB if DXT compressed).

If you're concerned about performance - don't be. The "source rectangle" parameter enables texture atlasing - this is not what you're doing here, though.

Furthermore, it is usually best to implement a game camera by passing a translation `Matrix` to `SpriteBatch.Begin`, and then `Draw`ing everything (background included) at fixed coordinates. You don't even need to specify a source rectangle for the background - the viewport will simply clip it.

If you wish to import textures that are larger than 4096 square, you could create a content pipeline extension to cut those large textures up into smaller ones. Or, if you only have a handful of fixed maps, it is easier just to separate them in your image editor.

Comment: I was concerned about performance, and thought that I was being very clever by saving it all to one texture... not sure why. Upon googling texture atlas, it seems that I was trying to use the source rectangle argument in a way that was not intended. I think I get the DXT thing, but I don't know how I would implement it in XNA... Also, if I were to draw a large amount of textures off-screen, would that hinder my performance, or is XNA smart about that somehow? Anwyay, I shall simply loop through my map tiles and implement your camera! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Max Probably not wise to draw lots of different textures off-screen if you can avoid it. If it's just a couple, though, it shouldn't be a problem. See [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288) for an in-depth description of the performance considerations. You can enable compression using the content pipeline: select your texture in VS, press F4 for properties, expand the "Content Processor" node and change the "Texture Format" setting to "DxtCompress". Note that this is a lossy compression.